# I want to combine characters to make a string

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "serialcomm.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#define BUFF_SIZE 256

int main()
{

    CSerialComm serialComm;

    BYTE buff[BUFF_SIZE] = { 0, };

    int op = 0;
    int port = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int size2 = 0;
    int restart = 0;
    char port_s[20] = "";
    char send_string[1000];
    char confirm[BUFF_SIZE];
    char dec[BUFF_SIZE];


    printf("select mode(1. send, 2. receive) : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &op);

    printf("insert port num : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &port);
    getchar();
    if (op == 1) {
        printf("plz submit data  (ex : 0x0a 0x01, 0x02, 0x0b) : ");
        gets_s(send_string, sizeof(send_string));
        size = serialComm.getHexData(send_string, buff);

        printf("read size(max %d) : ", BUFF_SIZE);
        scanf_s("%d", &size2);
    }


    sprintf_s(port_s, "COM%d", port);

    // STEP 1. SerialPort Connect
    if (!serialComm.connect(port_s)) {
        printf("connect faliled");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("connect successed\n");
    }

    if (op == 1) {
        // STEP 2. Send Command

        while (1) {



            if (!serialComm.sendCommand(buff, size)) {
                printf("send command failed\n");
            }
            else {
                int i = 0;
                printf("tx data(%d) : [ ", size);
                for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    printf("0x%02X ", buff[i]);
                }
                printf("]\n");
            }
            Sleep(2000);

            serialComm.readByte(buff, size2);

            int j = 0;
            printf("rx data(%d) : [ ", size2);
            for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
                printf("0x%02X ", buff[j]);
            }
            printf("]\n");


            //data convert
            char buffer[256];
            int m = 0;
            printf("[  ");
            for (m = 0; m < size; m++) {

                fprintf(stderr, "%d", buff[m]);
                printf("  ");
            }
            printf("]\n");

            sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", buff[m]);
            
            char data1 = buff[0];
            char data2 = buff[1];
            char data3 = buff[2];
            char data4 = buff[3];
            char data5 = buff[4];
            char data6 = buff[5];
            char data7 = buff[6];
            char data8 = buff[7];
            char data1 = buff[8];

            size = serialComm.getHexData(send_string, buff);
            Sleep(2000);
        }
```

The value of buff is

```
int m = 0;
                printf("[  ");
                for (m = 0; m < size; m++) {
                    printf("%d",buff[m]);
                    //fprintf(stderr, "%d", buff[m]);
                    printf("  ");
                }
                printf("]\n");
```

[  1  4  4  0  2  0  3  26  ]

I want to store this value as a string and output it, so I want to implement it by storing and concatenating the elements of the buff array one by one. However
C++ aggregate objects require initialization with'{...}'.
error appears. Is there a workaround or other good alternative?

Comment: Can you please post a complete program with `#include`s and `int main()`?

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense.  Why are you declaring the same `char` arrays twice?

Comment: Be aware that in 2021 [UTF-8 is used everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org) and in practice you need libraries (like [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [GNU libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) etc...) to handle them

Comment: Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and some good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html)

Comment: The code in the body goes into the main() function and #include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "serialcomm.h"
#include <set>
#include <string.h> // header file where strcat function is declared

Comment: @baeyeongbin: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67482222/edit) your question to improve it and provide some [mre]. If possible, avoid Chinese, since most readers don't know it

Comment: Use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: As per [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), perhaps a more reputable source, it looks like this is your best option:

```
#include <string>
std::string s = "[  " + std::string(buff, size) + "  ]";
```

As per [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-character-array-to-string-in-c/), it looks like this is your second best option:

```
// converts character array
// to string and returns it
string convertToString(char* a, int size)
{
    int i;
    string s = "";
    s = s + "[  ";
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        s = s + a[i];
    }
    s = s + "  ]";
    return s;
}
```

To get a string from your buff array:

```
string s = convertToString(buff, size);
```

Comment: *As per geeksforgeeks* -- A site that is not recommended when actually trying to write proper C++ code.  That entire loop is not necessary `s = "[ " + std::string(a, size) + " ]";`

Comment: Thank you. I will write it so that you can understand it from the next time.

Comment: I believe this is wrong, as they are trying to print the values of the bytes and not the characters (noticing the `"%d"`). In that case it has to be a loop with `std::to_string(a[i]) + ' '`.

Comment: @olm `"%d"` is an integer format specifier, check [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). This is why I think OP wants integer values.

Comment: @AdamTV Yes, but std::string does not automatically convert any values to readable integers. In both your examples it simply prints the (ascii) value of the chars. `char a[] = {65,66}` becomes "[ AB ]". This is why `std::to_string()` is needed to print "[ 65 66 ]".